# delete values in two files Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I did this before

```
INSERT INTO table.x VALUES (123)
```

but I inserted the wrong number. When i tried it again, it says it's duplicate. How do I remove the old values in this column?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the DDL of the table. Assuming this is valid equivalent of `INSERT INTO table (x) VALUES (123)` and there's not implicit type coercion going on (i.e. `x` is defined as a numeric type):

- If the duplicate error is because `x` is defined to be unique, you could simply `DELETE FROM table WHERE x = 123`
- If the duplicate is due to the table being `SET` (not `MULTISET` -- i.e. exact duplicate rows are not allowed), you should add `AND other_col IS NULL` for every other column in the table.